# Spivak Partitions of Unity

Tags: multivariable-calculus, manifolds

On page 65 of Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, he states
[image]

Why does $\int_A\phi \cdot |f|$ exist even if $A$ is not bounded? Thanks.

Comment: by definition of the partition of unity, the support of each $\phi$ is bounded, so the integral exist. of course he want to take the some over all $\phi\in \Phi$ and then he have to put some condition on $f$ which I believe he do in the next sentences

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @ali Thanks. Yes, the definition in the extended sense follows.